# What is the right way for extracting rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, code-reuse

I have 2 applications (sister apps for the same domain) which have some of the same resources such as Documents, Tasks, Access Rights etc.

How should I extract that out? As a Gem or an Engine?. Each resource has a model/controller/views/routes.

Any further pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Engines: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html
- Gems: https://guides.rubygems.org/

Other than saying your apps share common features, I don't think you've given enough information to get any real concrete advice.

Are you wanting to DRY up code? Provide standard routes? Share resources between apps? Bind models structurally to keep them in parity? Split app concerns while preserving relationships? Standardize privileges and authorizations?

Read these guides and see which option seems to meet your goals.

Comment: Specifically trying to share resources across apps, which includes the models, views and controllers etc.